# NYC Tapwater filter

Tags: kashrut-kosher, water, bugs

I recently moved to NYC and am concerned about [copepods](https://oukosher.org/blog/consumer-news/nyc-water/) etc. in the tap water. I can't install a fancy under-sink filter nor do I want to refill a Brita pitcher all the time. Are there any other options? I read online about an EZ Filter but haven't seen anywhere to buy it. I imagine that the insects are relatively large (as opposed to what Brita typically filters) so maybe just some type of fine mesh screen that fits over a spout?

TIA!

Comment: If they were that large everyone else would be grossed out

Comment: related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/61175/4940

Comment: @magicker72, the OU doesn't consider the copepods microorganisms. They can be seen by the visible eye. Admittedly it is only if you notice that they move oddly that you'll be able to distinguish them from air bubbles or dust. But you can see there is something there.

Comment: Some other background reading from Star-K - https://www.star-k.org/articles/kashrus-kurrents/5692/hot-off-the-hotline/

Comment: You could rely on bottled water.

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Max and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: Lettuce is over 96% water (accd to Google), so you could stay hydrated by eating lots of lettuce.