# Does anyone know how to Kosher water from the river or the ocean?

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, bugs, semicha, chulin-tractate

BH

Hi, recently I heard there was a case that happened in New York where there was a worry of little transparent bugs in the tap water my friend told me that the water essentially comes from the river so my question is if you draw a bucket of water from either a river or the sea how do you kosher the water that there is no bugs anymore and especially the really small ones and what are the sources about this in Halacha?

Comment: If you can't see the bugs even when looking closely it's kosher - though drinking the water might not be healthy...

Comment: ...The NYC copepods are/were visible as white specks

Comment: related (duplicate?): [Is there a concern regarding the kashrut of microorganisms?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/61175/11501)

Comment: Depends what they are. A filter that has holes smaller than the bugs should work.